# Placeholder for case class? Scala for comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have a piece of code as such (simplified): 
    import scala.concurrent.Future

```
case class BigCase(id: Int, v2: Int, v3: Int)

object Repo {
  def insert(i: BigCase):Future[Int] = ???

  val r = for {
    id <- insert(BigCase(1,2,3))
  } yield {
    id
  }

  println(s"result: $r")
}
```

It works fine, but when I have a huge "BigCase" class with 15 fields, it would be nice to be able to write

> insert(_)

, instead of

> insert(BigCase(1,2,3,4,5,6...))

, especially during the stub-out phase. But once I did `insert(_)`, id became type "Nothing" , which makes further steps hard to compose.

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your code is supposed to work but you are defining your `BigCase` instance for the first time within your comprehension. There is no way to shorten the declaration itself but I think your code makes more sense if the `BigCase` instance is defined before the for comprehension:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> def insert(bc: BigCase): Future[Int] = Future({Thread.sleep(1000); bc.id})
insert: (bc: BigCase)scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> val myBC = BigCase(1,2,3)
myBC: BigCase = BigCase(1,2,3)

scala> val r = for {id <- insert(myBC)} yield id
r: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@53bd8fca

scala> r.onComplete(println)
Success(1)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the question isn't really "how to make this work", rather, I'm hoping to find a way to call insert() without providing it a full-blown BigCase class during pseudo-code phase, kind of like calling insert(???) , but still have compiler return the correct return type.

Comment: Well you can't run anything with your `insert = ???`, do you just mean a placeholder for your compiler to use? `null` might work, otherwise you could have `insert` accept `Option[BigCase]` and pass it `None` when you don't want to copy in a long case class

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, `???: BigCase` will compile and work everywhere you want a `BigCase`. If you want to use the placeholder in multiple places, you can use `val bc: BigCase = ???`.

In fact, given the type of `insert`, `insert(???)` should already work fine, so it isn't clear what you mean in this comment:

> kind of like calling insert(???) , but still have compiler return the correct return type

Answer (score 0):

If you just want arbitrary int fields,

```
scala> case class BigCase(ids: Int*)
defined class BigCase

scala> BigCase(1 to 3 : _*)
res3: BigCase = BigCase(Range 1 to 3)
```

Then go back later and fix the number of fields?

or, more arbitrarily,

```
scala> case class BigCase[A](ids: A)
defined class BigCase

scala> BigCase(1,2,3)
res7: BigCase[(Int, Int, Int)] = BigCase((1,2,3))

scala> BigCase(1,2,"three")
res8: BigCase[(Int, Int, String)] = BigCase((1,2,three))
```

Comment: BigCase is actually a concrete diverse class, with Strings, DateTime, Int, Options, etc.

Comment: If you just want a container, with details you're going to work out a bit later, then res8. You could also just `type C = (Int, Int, String)`.